# Windows 10 shuts down when sleeping or hibernating

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, shutdown, hibernate

When I try to put my computer to sleep or hibernate, it stays on for a few minutes, and then proceeds to shut down. I have fast startup disabled, but for some reason the option to "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in Device Manager is greyed out. I enabled selective USB suspending, and I did an sfc /scannow to fix any corrupted files.

It managed to sleep and hibernate a few times, but the issue returned.

Is there some way I can check which devices keep my PC awake, and ultimately result in my PC shutting down?

I'm using Windows 10 20H2

EDIT: The issue began a few months ago, so my PC was sleeping/hibernating properly for about a year. It suddenly stopped sleeping/hibernating out of the blue.

EDIT2: I have a custom-built PC, so I have no specific drivers or programs that control power. Everything is the default Windows drivers/programs/settings/etc.

Comment: Make sure Windows is fully up to date. Update BIOS, Chipset driver if it has one, and Power Driver.  Reset Power Plan to default Balanced. Restart, set up Hibernation and try again.

Comment: @John It's definitely not Windows being out of date, as the issue occurred before I updated. I updated thinking it might fix the issue, but to no avail. I don't see how the BIOS being out of date might have anything to do with my problem, but nevertheless I might have changed a setting there, so thanks for pointing out the BIOS. I don't know what a Power Driver is.

Comment: Look on the Manufacturer's Support site for Drivers for your specific machine. Power Driver should be there.

Comment: @John It's a custom built PC so no power drivers except the default ones.

Comment: Similar question>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1553459/windows-10-shuts-down-instead-of-sleep?rq=1

Comment: @Moab They have a laptop, which is different than a custom built PC.

Comment: I am not sure. Look at drivers for all components and see if you can find something. Custom built computers may not have as long a lifespan as engineered computers.

Comment: A custom built PC has a MOBO from somewhere (asus, msi, gigabyte.. etc etc).  THAT is where you get your drivers.  Might not need any specific drivers if ACPI was implemented correctly.  More likley related to the chipset drivers coupled with UEFI firmware for the mobo which I guarantee exist.

Comment: @John ..  `Custom built computers may not have as long a lifespan as engineered computers` .. my experience has been the exact opposite.  I get was better drivers and support directly from Asus than I do from Dell or HP.  But that is only my experience.

Comment: Lads stay on topic, I'm not discussing whether a prebuilt PC is better or worse than a custom built PC. I also don't think this is a hardware issue, as my components are all <2 years old, sans power supply.

Comment: We got into drivers because that is a predominant cause of suspend a hibernation issue. If not that you may wish to consider a Windows 10 Repair Install (Media Creation Link) and start with the option to Keep Everything.

Comment: I got it to work, somehow. I posted an answer, so it's probably one of the things there. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it (hopefully permanently) by doing the following:

1. Ensuring all devices can be turned off by the computer (Go to Device Manager -> Properties (for each device -> Power Management -> Check "Allow this device to be turned off")
2. I changed the power plan to the Balanced Plan, and set the plan to it's default settings.
3. I have fast startup disabled, but I don't know if it helps or not
4. I went to Services -> Computer Browser and set it's startup to "Automatic" (Not sure if this is what helped, nor do I know what it does, so try at your own risk)

EDIT: Also, try unplugging any USB drives. Windows may not be able to eject them properly and result in the PC not sleeping and/or hibernating. The issue returned seemingly randomly, but I realized that my USB drive may not be turning off. After removing it, I was able to sleep/hibernate normally.

Answer (score 1):

Windows goes into Hibernation after being in sleep for a period of time. This is to save you from crashing windows in case you run out of battery, or have a power failure.

**Windows is NOT shutting down. It's going into hibernation which everyone thinks is shutting down.**

It's suppose to do that. Here's why and how to check how long it takes before shutting down. (Actually Hibernating, NOT shutting down.)

- Open Power and Sleep
- click "Additional power settings".
- click "Change when computer sleeps".
- click "Change advanced power settings".
  At this point a box will pop up.
- expand sleep
- expand Hibernate under sleep
  Here change how long it takes before going into hibernation which everyone thinks is shutting down.

Comment: If you read the question you would see that it stays on (ie. fans are spinning) after going to sleep, before promptly shutting down. This is not proper behaviour for Windows going to sleep. I think I can tell when a PC shuts down vs. when it goes into hibernate.